# error: The method 'signInWithPhoneNumber' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i can't find `signInWithPhoneNumber` method with firebaseAuth class

//main.dart code

```
signIn() {

    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode:smsCode)
        .then((user) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

//pubspec.yaml code

```
  dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  firebase_auth:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no method for `signWithPhoneNumber` in `FirebaseAuth`

to sign with phone number after code sent to user use `signInWithCredential` method

as example : this method will return **firebaseUser** if code passed is true and **null** if not

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getUserFromCodePhone(
      String code, String verificationID) async {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: code);
    try {
      AuthResult result = await mAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      FirebaseUser currentUser = await mAuth.currentUser();
      if (currentUser != null && result.user.uid == currentUser.uid) {
        return currentUser;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (_) {}

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: @BhagyashreeR welcome friend, please if my answer solve your problem make it correct